# React-router-dom v6 useNavigate not use the axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I am using axios request interceptor to set '`Authorization`' header. The page I want to navigate is having a axios call to backend. That axios call request pass to backend from UI without '`Authorization`' header when I use `useNavigate`

When making the axios call code hit the `useEffect` in `AxiosInterceptor`. But it doesn't fire the request interceptor `reqInterceptor`

Axios interceptor for request & response

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import KeycloakService from '../services/KeycloakService';
const instance = axios.create();

const AxiosInterceptor = ({ children }: any) => {
   const [isSet, setIsSet] = useState(false);

   const navigate = useNavigate();

   useEffect(() => {

      const reqInterceptor = (request: any) => {
         if (KeycloakService.isLoggedIn()) {
            const token = KeycloakService.getToken();
            request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
         }
         
         return request;
      };

      const resInterceptor = (response: any) => {
         return response;
      };

      const errInterceptor = (error: any) => {
         if (error.response.status === 401) {
            navigate('/home');
         }
         return Promise.reject(error);
      };

      const requestInterceptor = instance.interceptors.request.use(reqInterceptor, errInterceptor);
      const responseInterceptor = instance.interceptors.response.use(resInterceptor, errInterceptor);

      setIsSet(true);

      return () => {
         instance.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
         instance.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
      };

   }, [navigate]);

   return isSet && children;
};

export default instance;
export { AxiosInterceptor };
```

App.tsx

```
.... <BrowserRouter>
            <AuthProvider>

         <AxiosInterceptor>
               <Routes>
                  ...
               </Routes>
```

...

Navigation didn't work.

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate('/dashboard', { replace: true });
```

This is how I call axios

```
import axios from '../hooks/AxiosInterceptor';
public static async getAnswers(userId: string) {
      return await axios.get(makeApiRoute(`/answers/${userId}`));
   }
```

Comment: Does `AxiosInterceptor` need to be inside `AuthProvider` so the `useAuth` hook works? Can you provide more details *other than* "it didn't work"? Are there any errors? What debugging steps have been taken?

Comment: I update the question. AxiosInterceptor need inside of  AuthProvider. But that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: What is the specific issue you are asking about? Navigating or the request header? The `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function have nothing at all to do with making API/axios requests. All `navigate` does is navigate to paths the app is rendering routes for. I thought you were saying the error interceptor wasn't calling `navigate("/home");`.

Comment: Please check for typos using a tool like Grammarly. Because i couldn't understand what do you mean. . Also provide a section on what do you expect to happen

Comment: I think it better to have protected routes and try to get a refresh token using axios intereptors if refresh fails just set the auth info/user to null, you can use [axios auth refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh)

Comment: Hope I added more clarity to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axios interceptor is not correct. Just one line need to update to correctly work with useNavigate.

Valid

```
useEffect(() => {
...

   }, []);
```

Invalid

```
   useEffect(() => {

     .....
   }, [navigate]);
```